# Sending a single-packet HTTP response in Node.js

Tags: node.js, tcp, packet

To show my students a simple HTTP request and response that they could capture using Wireshark, I whipped up a simple Node.js HTTP server:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var port = 80;
var file = process.argv[2]; //This file contains a 42 byte HTML page

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type' : 'text/html' }); // Sends first packet
  fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res); // Sends second packet
}).listen(port);
```

Unfortunately, the two lines transmitting the HTTP header and the HTML are sent as two separate TCP packets (even though they are both quite small). It would be simpler for my students if the HTTP header and HTML were just one packet. How could I change my code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');    
var file = process.argv[2];

http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html;"});  
    fs.readFile(file, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            throw err; 
        }    
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    });
}).listen(8000);
```

the reason it won't work is that Node.js runs everything asynchronously. When you are loading your html file, the server creation starts the same time. By the time you are about to write your html to your tcp socket, the file most likely won't be ready.

---

I see what you were trying to do before... I misread your code because of the indentation. Let me know if this snippet works.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not that you're correct. If you were, then transmitting a string would work fine (since we wouldn't have to wait on a file read).

Answer (score 0):

try using something like-

```
var file = process.argv[2];
fs.readFile(file, function (err, html) {
if (err) {
    throw err; 
}       
http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write(html);  
    response.end();  
}).listen(8000);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I tried this approach and it does not appear to work.